Unable to setup HTTPS using Nginx, Certbot and Docker
I am currently working to setup Docker in order to deploy the website I created. However, I'm stuck at the level of configuring https with Nginx and Certbot.
Here is everything I did :

Bought a domain name on OVH Cloud and added an A entry in the DNS pointing to my local windows machine (on which i run the containers to test if the website is working)
Created the docker-compose.yml file with the following content :

services:
    mysql_database:
        build: ./database
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: test
            MYSQL_DATABASE: ranking
        ports:
            - 3316:3306
  
    flask-api:
        build: ./server
        environment:
            MYSQL_HOST: mysql_database
            MYSQL_PORT: 3306
            MYSQL_DATABASE: ranking
            MYSQL_USER: root
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: test
            DEBUG: False
            SMASHGG_API_KEY: 1132567b3267
        depends_on:
            - mysql_database
  
    frontend:
        build: ./client
        ports: 
            - 80:80
            - 443:443
        volumes:
            - ./certbot/www/:/var/www/certbot/:ro
            - ./certbot/conf/:/etc/nginx/ssl/:ro
        depends_on:
            - flask-api
  
    certbot:
        image: certbot/certbot:latest
        volumes:
            - ./certbot/www/:/var/www/certbot/:rw
            - ./certbot/conf/:/ect/letsencrypt/:rw


Where the frontend service is build using this Dockerfile :

# Utiliser une image Nginx de base
FROM nginx:latest

# Supprimer le fichier de configuration par défaut de Nginx
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

# Copier le fichier de configuration personnalisé
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d

# Copier les fichiers de build de Vue.js dans le répertoire d'hébergement de Nginx
COPY dist/ /usr/share/nginx/html

# Exposer le port 80 pour le serveur web
EXPOSE 80


And the nginx.conf file is this one :


    events {
        worker_connections 1024;
    }
    
    http {    
        server {
            listen 80;
    
            server_name seeding.gg www.seeding.gg;
    
            location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
                root /var/www/certbot;
            }
    
            location / {
                return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
            }
        }
    
        server {
            listen 443 ssl;
    
            server_name seeding.gg www.seeding.gg;
    
            ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/live/seeding.gg/fullchain.pem;
            ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/live/seeding.gg/privkey.pem;
            
            location / {
                root /usr/share/nginx/html;
                index index.html;
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
            }
    
            location /api/ {
                proxy_pass http://flask-api:5000/;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            }
        }
    }



Created a folder named certbot that contains 2 folders named conf and www that are currently empty (for the volumes)
Added 1 inbound rule to my firewall for ports 80 and 443
Added 1 outbound rule to my firewall for ports 80 and 443

However, when I run the command docker compose run --rm certbot certonly --webroot --webroot-path /var/www/certbot/ -d www.seeding.gg to get the certificates, I get the following error :
Certbot failed to authenticate some domains (authenticator: webroot). The Certificate Authority reported these problems:
    Domain: www.seeding.gg
    Type:   dns
    Detail: no valid A records found for www.seeding.gg; no valid AAAA records found for www.seeding.gg

Hint: The Certificate Authority failed to download the temporary challenge files created by Certbot. Ensure that the listed domains serve their content from the provided --webroot-path/-w and that files created there can be downloaded from the internet.

Some challenges have failed.
Ask for help or search for solutions at https://community.letsencrypt.org. See the logfile /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log or re-run Certbot with -v for more details.

Could you help me with this issue please ?

A while ago I wrote an article on this subject: How to have Nginx in a Docker container with SSL. Check it out here: https://bertcatsburg.github.io/docs/category/nginx-in-docker/
